# How to intercept capture TAB key in WinForms application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, keystroke

I'm trying to capture the *Tab* key in a Windows Forms application and do a custom action when it is pressed.

I have a Form with several listViews and buttons, I've set the Form's *KeyPreview* property to true and when I press any other key than tab, my KeyDown event handler does get called.

But that's not true with the *Tab* key - I don't receive WM_KEYDOWN message even in WndProc.

Do I need to set each control inside my form - its *TabStop* property - to false? There must be a more elegant way than that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

will [this](http://amsakanna.blogspot.com/2008/09/catching-arrow-keys-in-vb-net.html) help you?

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
  Dim keyPressed As Keys = CType(msg.WParam.ToInt32(), Keys)

  Select Case keyPressed
    Case Keys.Right msgbox("Right Arrow Key Caught")
    Case Keys.Left msgbox("LeftArrow Key Caught")
    Case Keys.Up msgbox("Up Arrow Key Caught")
    Case Keys.Down msgbox("Down Arrow Key Caught")
    Case Else Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
  End Select
End Function
```

Comment: yes! thanks. So for completion's sake, I had to override Form's ProcessCmdKey event and check if (keyData & Keys.Tab) == Keys.Tab.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 35):

This is the C# code similar to the VB code given in the answer above...

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Tab)
        {
            //your code
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Certainly helped me. An upvote for providing the code for the language that the question was tagged under.

Comment: This example continues propagation.  You need to return 'true' from ProcessCmdKey to stop other handling of the key press, which is often the intended behavior (only one thing handles it).

Comment: @Ram, is there anyway to know on which control tabkey was pressed?

Answer (score 7):

You can use "PreviewKeyDown" Event

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub form1_KeyDown(.... ) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        SendKeys.Send("{tab}")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: that really doesn't have anything to do with the question - you intercept Enter key and send Tab afterwards...