# Tab Key Functionality Using Enter Key in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, textbox

I have a form with nearly 20 Textbox and 5 Combobox  and one control in dependent on the other,
Now I want to write the code for the form in such a way that, Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> Key and <kbd>Tab</kbd> Key should have the same functionality.

Like on pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> Key the focus moves to next control should also be performed when I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> Key.
Similarly when I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> Key, there is some process code written in key press event but this should also be performed when I press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> Key.

Comment: Will this form be used to submit data?  I'm sure it can be done, but modifying the typical power user keys to do this just seems like a bad idea...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way that I have accomplished it in Winforms is by using the [`SelectNextControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol.aspx) Method.

i.e.

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
    Dim tb As TextBox
    tb = CType(sender, TextBox)

    If Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
        If e.KeyChar.Equals(Chr(Keys.Return)) Then
            Me.SelectNextControl(tb, True, True, False, True)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If you are using WPF you can use [`TraversalRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.traversalrequest.aspx#Y0)

i.e.

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs)
    Dim tb As TextBox
    tb = CType(sender, TextBox)

    If e.Key = Key.Return Then
        tb.MoveFocus(New TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next))
    ElseIf e.Key = Key.Tab Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

As far as intercepting the <kbd>Tab</kbd> Key take a look at this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461512/how-to-intercept-capture-tab-key-in-winforms-application).

Answer (score 12):

First Make your Form's Keypreview property= True
And Then Paste The Code Below in Form's Keydown Event

```
 If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    Me.SelectNextControl(Me.ActiveControl, True, True, True, False) 'for Select Next Control
End If
```

Comment: Good result with three line coding.

Answer (score 1):

simply make following function

```
Public Sub perform_tab_on_enter(ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) 
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then 
  SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
else
  exit sub
End If
e.SuppressKeyPress = True 'this will prevent ding sound 
End Sub
```

call this function on control's keydown event

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this without having to manually create or set event handlers for each control.  At the initialization of the form, I run a function that loops through every control and adds a generic handler function.

```
Private Sub AddHandlers()
    Try
        'Get the first control in the tab order.
        Dim ctl As Windows.Forms.Control = Me.GetNextControl(Me, True)
        Do Until ctl Is Nothing
            If TypeOf ctl Is System.Windows.Forms.TextBox Or TypeOf ctl Is System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox _
                    Or TypeOf ctl Is System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox Or TypeOf ctl Is System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker Then

                AddHandler ctl.KeyDown, AddressOf ReturnKeyTabs
            End If
            'Get the next control in the tab order.
            ctl = Me.GetNextControl(ctl, True)
        Loop
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ReturnKeyTabs(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Return Then
        e.Handled = True
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
    ReturnKeyTabs(e.KeyCode)
End Sub

Private Sub ReturnKeyTabs(ByVal KeyCode As System.Windows.Forms.Keys)
    If KeyCode = System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Return Then
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{Tab}")
        KeyCode = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the KeyPreview property of the form to True in the form's Load event and handle the KeyDown event of the form. Then, you can check if the active control is a text box and the pressed key is the Enter key, and if so, you can set the Handled property of the event to True and use the SelectNextControl method to move the focus to the next control in the tab order (example uses Form1).

```
Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub
```

Then add this code:

```
    Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles myBase.KeyDown
        If TypeOf Me.ActiveControl Is TextBox AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            e.Handled = True
            Me.SelectNextControl(Me.ActiveControl, True, True, True, True)
        End If
    End Sub
```

This should allow the Enter key to act as a Tab key when the focus is on a text box in the form.

Answer (score 0):

A better option that I uses for the same problem is to create a new textbox class textboxClass and paste following code in its keypress event

```
    Private Sub commonTextbox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
            If Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
                If e.KeyChar.Equals(Chr(Keys.Return)) Then
                    Me.Parent.SelectNextControl(Me, True, True, False, True)
                    e.Handled = True
                End If
            End If
    End Sub
```

Now we can add any number of textbox to any form. it will behave as desired. when enter is pressed on the last textbox focus goes to first one.

This code as taken from @Mark Hall for single textbox from this page only.

Answer (score -1):

This is quite old but I got here because I wanted to do the same thing. The problem with some of the answers here is that they will always jump to the next control when pressing enter and I only want it to do that with text boxes. If they get to a button, I want them to be able to hit enter to "click" that button. So here is what I did.

```
Private Sub txtName_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtName.KeyPress, txtAttn.KeyPress, txtAdd1.KeyPress, txtAdd2.KeyPress, txtCity.KeyPress, txtState.KeyPress, txtZip.KeyPress

    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
        e.Handled = True
        SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}")
    End If

End Sub
```

It is kind of a pain having to add all of the .keypress in the handles part of the sub but then you can control which items will cause it to move to the next control and which will not. Of course you also have to set the tab stops order at design time for this to work. But with this method, it can still trigger a button press once it tabs to a button and they hit enter again.

I would have just added this as a comment but I do not have enough points to add comments. :)

Answer (score -5):

You can do it with some javascript:
[Enter Key Focus](http://javascriptsource.com/forms/enter-key-focus.html)