# Capturing tab key only for a specific textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, overriding

I have a winforms application that is reading information from a barcode scanner.

The scanner uses a <kbd>tab</kbd> suffix to confirm the reading of the barcode.

I need to trap this in a specific textbox only but keep the functionality intact everywhere else.

I have looked through this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461512/how-to-intercept-capture-tab-key-in-winforms-application) and also this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isinputkey.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) and so far nothing is working for me.
If possible I want to avoid trapping ALL tab events on the form and only trap those in a certain textbox during a certain state.

The MSDN Article seems to do what I need but I'm not declaring the textbox in code so can't work out how to override the functions.

Can anyone suggest a way to capture <kbd>tab</kbd> in a single textbox?

Comment: Just a suggestion : How about using the tab index of the required text box...You capture the tab according to the text box tab index property

Comment: @VB.NETLEARNER Sorry I don't follow, could you give/link to an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the <kbd>tab</kbd> key by making use of the `previewkeydown` of the particular text box.

Try this out,

**In Preview key down,**

```
private sub Textbox1_PreviewKeydown(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) _
Handles Textbox1.PreviewKeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
            e.IsInputKey = True
    End If

End sub
```

**In key down,**

```
Private Sub Textbox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Textbox1.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then ''Your code goes here

End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, in fact this has simplified 3 other subs for different keys into one!